# how to deploy an Angular2 Typescript based application is AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, angular, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, angular2-routing

I want to deploy Angular 2 in a static server .I do not want to deploy it with Node. Js. Is it possible to run Angular Based application in AWS S3? How to deploy it to S3...

Comment: Do you use Angular CLI?

Comment: No..I am not using Angular CLI

Comment: How do you run your client code locally?

Comment: just using npm start

Comment: Help me help you. Can you post the `scripts` section in your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package your application to the dist folder by using the following command to generate transpiled js files and the other image, css assets and then upload to AWS S3.

Angular CLI: `ng build -prod`
WebPack: `npm run build_prod`

Not sure if pretty urls will be full supported on page refresh but I use the following in Nginx to forward all url requests back to index.html

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}
```

Finally: I would still recommend hosting any web app in a real web server if you can but any system that can serve files through http should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) .

With that you can generate a production folder (dist) with index.html and all the assets, then you can deploy that folder to a static server.

Answer (score 0):

In the S3 bucket Static Hosting Error page, set it to index.html to allow the router to navigate routes you designate for the components, you have to upload the node_modules folder, unless you use CD/CI framework to deploy, which deploy the installed modules automatically.